# Getting white spaces for elements outside the recyclerview in Andorid

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/weekDropdown"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:hint="Select Week"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_round_calendar_today_24">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/weekSelected"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".PickemPicksheetActivity">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/lbl_tp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the layout i have the following elements:

1. TextInputLayout/AutoCompleteTextView used as a Dropdown
2. RecyclerView
3. EditText

The RecyclerView is linked to the following layout, which creates the list of items:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/rootView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/gamefield_background" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/awayTeam"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|left" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/homeTeam"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:scaleX="-1" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        
    </FrameLayout>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

As stated above this creates the list of items that get inflated by the adapter.

This is the output of the above :

[image]

As you can see there is a big white space at the start of the view where the dropdown should be!?

Only once I click on it, because I know its there does the following show up:

[image]

The same thing happens with the EditText at the bottom of the view where there is a big white space until i click there and enter text does something show up!?

I think it has something to do with the fact that the two elements : dropdown and edittext are on the outside of the recyclerview which is created by the Adapter... my only problem is I dont understand how to fix it?

If I bring in the two elements into the recylerview then it will get iterated along with the game entries.

Is there a way to pass the elements to the adapter class?

### UPDATE:

Adding image for the bottom of the view which shows the white space there that should be a EditText but not displaying unless I click there.

[image]

Also note scrolling down to the bottom of the list will cause the dropdown to `hide` again when i scroll back up, as the recyclerview likely recycled the view during scrolling so i would have to click on the white space again for it element to be displayed again.

Here is the code for my sheetActivity where it calls the recyclerview:

```
adapter = new PickemSheetAdapter(sheetActivity.this, gameList, pickList, totalPoints);

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The adapterView is as follows:

```
class GameViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView awayTeamImageView, homeTeamImageView;


    public GameViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        awayTeamImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.awayTeam);

        homeTeamImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.homeTeam);

    }




    public class PickemSheetAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PickemSheetAdapter.GameViewHolder> {

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(PickemSheetAdapter.GameViewHolder holder, int position) {

            final Games game = gameList.get(position);

   
  holder.awayTeamImageView.setBackgroundResource(awayResourceId);

   
  holder.homeTeamImageView.setBackgroundResource(awayResourceId);

    }

}
```

Comment: there is a view named Spinner, you should use that to display a drop-down

Comment: That does not solve my problem regardless, the exact same thing would occur even if i used a `Spinner`, it would be declared outside the recyclerview and would not be displayed just like the dropdown.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, spinner is the dropdown, right? Of course it would be outside your recyclerview because of layout definition. What is the problem with that?

Comment: I just added another image of my issue, at the bottom of the view the `EditText` also does not display on load of the view unless I click there. So it doesnt matter what element I place there, its not being displayed correctly is the issue I am trying to resolve with my question, not if I should use a `Spinner` or `Dropdown`

Comment: My callout and what I am looking for help with is why both those items which as can be seen in my xml layouts is that they are both declared outside the recyclerview and they are both not being displayed by default unless I click on them.

Comment: can you provide the screenshot of the layout in preview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main reason for your issue is at 5th line where

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
```

if you remove this everything will appear just fine.
I think that in `Theme.MaterialComponents` every color is set to white and because of that you can't see the elements with a white background. if you insist on using `Theme.MaterialComponents` then you have to change color of every element that you use to another color.

also there is no reason to put your `RecyclerView` inside that `RelativeLayout` and you should move that outside and remove the `RelativeLayout`

Comment: You are 100% correct! Wow I have been trying to troubleshoot this for hours... I need to Android so I dont know all the ins and outs yet!? As stupid as it sounds I still need to understand the themes and how they effect the UI.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest you find more resources about android layout. Your layout is so confused and complicated.

About your question: the top part (auto complete text) you set background to `@null`, so you wont see it until you click. The bottom is for the reason that you set layout's `width` to wrap content, and nothing is in there so... blank.

Again, I want to emphasize the first thing I told you.

Comment: I removed the `android:background="@null"` and the exact same behavior is occurring. Still a blank  space until in click into it at the top. I also changed the bottom width as you suggested and the exact same behavior there too.

Comment: How does it look in xml?

Comment: I am not sure your question, I have included the xml layout for both the layouts? I also added the java code for the mainActivity which calls the recycler adapter to build the list of items.